# Have the major bugs in Stronghold 3 been fixed yet?

Tags: stronghold-3

*Stronghold 3* was released on the 25th of October 2011 and contained many bugs. I know the game has been patched through Steam multiple times, but I'm uncertain what those patches have done.

Have any of the major bugs been fixed in *Stronghold 3* since its release? Is the current build Stable?

Comment: Right now this comes across as a fairly subjective question; I'd probably dwell more on *if it's been effectively patched* versus is it *worth it*

Comment: Your previous question was a game-rec question, and highly subjective. I've edited your question to focus solely on how buggy the game, and if it ha been patched. However I'm worried that may be considered too localized, so it is possible your question may be closed.

Comment: Yeah, what @NickT said. This question is currently teetering on what is acceptable here. Also, welcome to [Gaming.SE]! You should check the [faq] to see what questions are appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the revision history for the Steam version here:

http://store.steampowered.com/news/?appids=47400

It is up to you to compare this list to the bugs the reviews are complaining about and/or you want to see fixed before plunging the money for it.